# MaterialTable Sticky Header and Columns

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a problem with materialTable https://material-table.com/#/ because I can't combine fixing the header and fixing columns on the left

Comment: Add more details, what code you are trying?

Comment: maxBodyHeight: 400,    
fixedColumns: {
      right: 4
   }

Comment: I have this in my option props of MaterialTable

Comment: maxBodyHeight: 400,    
 fixedColumns: {
     right: 4
}

Comment: maxBodyHeight for sticky header

Comment: and fixedColumns for fixed the 4 first columns of the table

Answer (score 0):

It does'n have that feature, but you can add it with custom css

```
table {
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}
th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```